# Helm Nginx Ingress - how to specify External IP in "helm install" command

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I need to specify External IP that will be associated to Nginx service upon the Ingress Controller creation using the HELM install:

```
helm install nginx-ingress ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx -f internal-ingress.yaml 
--set controller.nodeSelector."beta\.kubernetes\.io/os"=linux 
--set defaultBackend.nodeSelector."beta\.kubernetes\.io/os"=linux
```

So I want to set statically EXTERNAL-IP address that can be seen upon this creation:

```
kubectl get services
NAME                                     TYPE          CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                                     AGE

nginx-ingress-ingress-nginx-controller   LoadBalancer  10.0.36.81   10.33.27.35   80:31312/TCP,443:30653/TCP   5d
```

I need this because DNS configuration has already been set up for this IP and I would like to avoid this kind of configuration again.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add flag to installation command:

```
 --set controller.service.loadBalancerIP=XXXX
```

where XXXX is static EXTERNAL IP you want to use.
Remember that  IP needs to be regional and in the same region as the cluster.

See: [external-ip-ingress-controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55421381/how-to-add-a-static-ip-to-nginx-ingress-installed-via-helm).